# Finding all affected targets due to source change in cmake project

Tags: cmake

In a cmake based project (C/C++), if there is a change done in a source file, I would like a means to dump list of affected targets (including transitive dependencies).

I am considering:

1. Generate source to .o mapping => generate build files using -GNinja and parse the CMakeFiles/.dir/.o.d files
2. Generate a parseable output of --graphviz option => no solution yet
3. Figure out a way to handle dependencies added to custom targets using add_dependencies() => no solution yet

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you can use a dry-run and extract the information from it? -n is the flag for Ninja and Make.

Comment: Parsing make output would be a bit clunky. Its output varies depending on whether make has been run or not. Since cmake has the targets and dependcy information, I am hoping there is a cleaner cmake specific solution.

Comment: The query option of Ninja works well for my purpose, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supporting @usr1234567's comment, I'm using your first `-G Ninja` approach if I want to know the dependencies.

[ninja](/questions/tagged/ninja) does have a lot of [tool/debug options](https://ninja-build.org/manual.html#_extra_tools) to support you:

```
> ninja -t query CMakeFiles\HelloWorld.dir\main.obj

CMakeFiles/HelloWorld.dir/main.obj:
  input: CXX_COMPILER__HelloWorld
    ../main.cpp
  outputs:
    HelloWorld.exe
```

Or the mentioned "dry run" with:

```
> ninja -d explain -n
```

A [cmake](/questions/tagged/cmake) specific approach would be more complicated. For a starting point refer to ["make dist" equivalent in CMake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625503/make-dist-equivalent-in-cmake).

Comment: The query option of Ninja works well for my purpose.